# How to handle _platformCallHandler call speech.onError 7?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement the speech_recognition plugin in the flutter. And the recognition works perfectly when I speak and the app runs smoothly. but when I click on the mic button and speak nothing it shows the following error and then the functionality of the mic button stops until i restart the app.

```
D/SpeechRecognitionPlugin( 1155): onError : 7
I/flutter ( 1155): _platformCallHandler call speech.onSpeechAvailability false
I/flutter ( 1155): _platformCallHandler call speech.onError 7
I/flutter ( 1155): Unknowm method speech.onError
```

Can anyone please help me with this issue

this is my speech_recognition.dart file

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

typedef void AvailabilityHandler(bool result);
typedef void StringResultHandler(String text);

/// the channel to control the speech recognition
class SpeechRecognition {
  static const MethodChannel _channel =
      const MethodChannel('speech_recognition');

  static final SpeechRecognition _speech = new SpeechRecognition._internal();

  factory SpeechRecognition() => _speech;

  SpeechRecognition._internal() {
    _channel.setMethodCallHandler(_platformCallHandler);
  }

  AvailabilityHandler availabilityHandler;

  StringResultHandler currentLocaleHandler;
  StringResultHandler recognitionResultHandler;

  VoidCallback recognitionStartedHandler;

  VoidCallback recognitionCompleteHandler;
  VoidCallback errorHandler;

  /// ask for speech  recognizer permission
  Future activate() => _channel.invokeMethod("speech.activate");

  /// start listening
  Future listen({String locale}) =>
      _channel.invokeMethod("speech.listen", locale);

  Future cancel() => _channel.invokeMethod("speech.cancel");

  Future stop() => _channel.invokeMethod("speech.stop");

  Future _platformCallHandler(MethodCall call) async {
    print("_platformCallHandler call ${call.method} ${call.arguments}");
    switch (call.method) {
      case "speech.onSpeechAvailability":
        availabilityHandler(call.arguments);
        break;
      case "speech.onCurrentLocale":
        currentLocaleHandler(call.arguments);
        break;
      case "speech.onSpeech":
        recognitionResultHandler(call.arguments);
        break;
      case "speech.onRecognitionStarted":
        recognitionStartedHandler();
        break;
      case "speech.onRecognitionComplete":
        recognitionCompleteHandler();
        break;
      case "speech.onError":
        errorHandler();
        break;
      default:
        print('Unknowm method ${call.method} ');
    }
  }

  // define a method to handle availability / permission result
  void setAvailabilityHandler(AvailabilityHandler handler) =>
      availabilityHandler = handler;

  // define a method to handle recognition result
  void setRecognitionResultHandler(StringResultHandler handler) =>
      recognitionResultHandler = handler;

  // define a method to handle native call
  void setRecognitionStartedHandler(VoidCallback handler) =>
      recognitionStartedHandler = handler;

  // define a method to handle native call
  void setRecognitionCompleteHandler(VoidCallback handler) =>
      recognitionCompleteHandler = handler;

  void setCurrentLocaleHandler(StringResultHandler handler) =>
      currentLocaleHandler = handler;

  void setErrorHandler(VoidCallback handler) => errorHandler = handler;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`speech_recognition` is not maintained actively. There are so many pull requests still waiting to be merged. You can prefer [speech_to_text](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text) library.

In the `_platformCallHandler` function before the `default` case add the below case.

```
case "speech.onError":
   errorHandler();
   break;
```

Declare `errorHandler` below `recognitionCompleteHandler`.

```
VoidCallback errorHandler;
```

At the end of the file, declare the public method to set this `errorHandler`

```
void setErrorHandler(VoidCallback handler) => errorHandler = handler;
```

This is lot of work, so you can use the [flutter_speech](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_speech) library which already implemented the above functions.

In your implementation, handle the error handler

```
_speechRecognition.setErrorHandler(() {
   initSpeechRecognizer();
});
```

Comment: I have changed as you asked but I still got the same output. And I have to change lot of code in order to implement the flutter_speech or sppech_to_text plugin which is the main reason I want to solve the issue if possible

Comment: I have even added the speech_recognition.dart file above please take a look at that

Comment: `speech_recognition.dart` file code I've. Please add your implementation code, so we can check it.

Comment: https://github.com/umakanth-pendyala/Flutter-voice-control/blob/master/lib/main.dart is the link to the implementation file please take a look at that

Comment: @UmakanthPendyala, you have to handle the `setErrorHandler` which you've defined in `speech_recognition.dart`. updated my answer, please see. My suggestion is to use `flutter_speech` which is exact copy of `speech_recognition` but this library added the error handling.

Comment: Excellent, it's working perfectly now. and I will be using flutter_speech from now on. And seriously at first, I tried to implement speed_to_text but realized the documentation isn't quite good. Anyways thanks for the help, if I have any other doubts I will contact you.